# Is there a way to add a new language to antv s2 library?

Tags: reactjs, antv

I am using antv s2 library in my application which handle french and english languages.
Antv S2 only have Chineese and English languages natively.
Is there a way to add a new one?

I don't see anything about it in the [Internationalization doc](https://s2.antv.vision/en/manual/basic/i18n).
When trying to extended internationalization I can only add keys to english and chineese languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`extendLocale`](https://github.com/antvis/S2/blob/fc5db4780f5a0a1cc64223e8270ecb67f30e6401/packages/s2-core/src/common/i18n/index.ts#L33) function to extend the internationalized text.

```
import { PivotSheet, setLang, extendLocale, i18n, getLang } from "@antv/s2";

extendLocale({
    jp: {
        小计: "小計",
        总计: "合計",
        总和: "集合体",
        项: "項",
        已选择: "厳選された",
        //...
    },
});
setLang("jp");
console.log(i18n("已选择"), getLang()); // 厳選された jp
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the signature of extendLocale is `const extendLocale: (extraLocale: LocaleType) => void;` where
```export declare type LocaleType = {
    [K in LangType]: Record<string, string>;
};``` and `type LangType = 'zh_CN' | 'en_US';`.

Comment: So as I said, when trying to extended internationalization I can only add keys to english and chineese languages.